# Rolling standard deviation in sas

Tags: sas, standard-deviation

Please help me with the sas code. I need to calculate rolling standard deviation by firm (permno) within 60 months. For this is use the following code:

```
proc sort data = Crsp;
 by permno date;
 run; 

proc expand data = Crsp out = std_a;
 by permno;
 convert ret=rw3_std / transformout = (movstd 60 trim 59);
 run;
```

What it does is it provides me with the standard deviations, but after calculating some standard deviations it provides no calculations. For example, it starts to provide stand. dev. from observation 60 (since the trim is 59) and after 280th observation it does not calculate stand. deviation even there are observations. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. Check if a new PERMO starts on record 280 and therefore you're in a new 'permo' and it's set to missing accordingly.

Comment: Please improve your question with an example we can test. 
Preferably reduce the size of datasets by lowering movstd and trim. 
Preferably use one of the datasets in the SASHELP library as input.